# No such module 'Parse' while Build the application Xcode 7.2 iOS9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I would like to use Parse.com Framework. I downloaded Parse.framework data folder from parse.com, added it to my project, then I added required frameworks in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and I was trying to run my application, but it doesn't work. I receive an error with the information `No such module "Parse"`.

I was trying to find any solution of this problem for last 4 hours, and I don't have any idea, how can I solve my problem. Could I ask you, for solution, how to add this framework to my project correctly?

Comment: youre using pods? or adding by downloading

Comment: We would need to see screenshots of your setup to see what you've done so far. Also, it would be wiser if you used cocoapods instead of including it manually.

Comment: I am doing it using pods, but in this case I create a new project, but still don't have any idea how to import this framework to existing project. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Please use pods for adding `Parse` into your application. Follow these steps to setup pods into your project.
1) open terminal
2) cd to directory of project
3) Run command `pod init`
4) Above command generate `PodFile` in project directory
5) Open PodFile and paste following line

```
pod 'Parse'
```

6) Run command `pod install`
7) Close Project and Open `Project_Name.xcworkspace` file onwards
8) Setup parse and build project.

It should works perfectly and you not need to manage any dependencies and build settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the box "Copy items if needed" when You dragged the Parse's framework to project?

If yes, go in Target > Build Settings and search for **Framework Search Paths**. You need to inform where build will search for frameworks, add directory **$(PROJECT_DIR)**, clean project (cmd + k) and build again.

It worked for me.
Cheers